# How can I update content from 3 tables in one query? - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables users, game and location; I would like to update the 3 tables at the same time in one query using PostgreSQL. I will be using node Js with express, So I can't use transaction nor would I like to. How is this to be done?

Comment: Why  not run three queries?

Comment: Im using nodejs and postgresql to run it, and running 3 queries doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) statement documentation, there is no way to update 3 tables (well unless the table inheritence is used, but I guess it is not). `table_name` describes single table.

**Solutions:**

1. To update 3 tables in one statemenet you may write a [stored function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) that does that and then calling it from your code. Functions body is executed in single transaction.
2. Use transactions like described in https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/nodejs-and-the-postgres-transaction-968 . I don't know a reason why using transactions in node.js application should be discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update three tables with a single UPDATE statement, but you can update three tables with a single SQL statement using [a data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with update_one as (
  update first_table 
     set some_column = ...
  where ...
), update_two as (
  update second_table
     set some_column = ...
  where ...
)
update third_table
   set some_column = ...
where ...
;
```

Comment: Can this be used with " app.put("/af/:user_id:", async (req, res) => " from express?